# Untaring files into a new folder

Tags: linux, tar

I've got a bunch of tar and tar.gz files that I would like to unzip.  Inside these files, most of them have the same folder structure zipped up inside (although with different files).

If I were to do this manually by right-clicking and selecting "Extract Here," it'd would create a new folder for me with the original file name and dump the files there.

However, when I do this via the command line, the behavior isn't always the same.  Sometimes it'd create the desired new folder and other times it wouldn't, causing it to overwrite the extraction of others.

Using the -C option seems to require the folder already existing.  How can I mimic the behavior of the manual "Extract Here" in the command line?

Thanks.

Comment: The gui is not just untarring. It's creating the subdir for you, which is outside tar's perview. You could whip up a quickie shell script that creates the dir for you then untars into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a bash function like this;

```
function untarhere() {
   (mkdir -P $1; cd $1; tar xzf $2)
}
```

and then call it like

```
   untarhere /your/destination/directory  /your/tar/file.tar
```